# addAnnotation not updating Map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I created the following method to add pins to my map view. I have tried calling it to get it to add the single pin but it does nothing when I call it from a different view controller?

```
-(void)addPins:(NSDecimalNumber*) woX ycoord:(NSDecimalNumber*) woY {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = 35;
    coordinate.longitude = -80;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [annotation setTitle:@"Title"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

I can call it from viewDidLoad of the DetailViewController and it will display the single pin:

```
[self addPins:woX ycoord:woY];
```

But when I call it from the MasterViewController nothing displays, but will log the comments so I know that it was run?

```
DetailViewController *firstController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];  
[firstController addPins:woX ycoord:woY];
```

Comment: Coordinate initialization looks fine.  When you call it from Master, you are doing alloc+init of Detail which creates a new instance.  You need to either present (show) this new instance or (more likely), you should be getting a reference to the already-presented instance and call addPins on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anna was on the right path. I was creating a new instance of the DetailViewController.

I was able to solve it by adding

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

to the MasterViewController.h. And then just calling

```
[self.detailViewController addPins:woX ycoord:woY desc:cellView];
```

in MasterViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because the map object doesn't loaded yet in memory when you calling `[firstController addPins:woX ycoord:woY];` can you try to call it after delay like this way `[firstController performSelectorWithObjects:@[woX, woY] afterDelay:1.0f]`

Good luck

Comment: That's not it. I am actually calling it from a button press in the second controller.